# Transfer a user straight away to a specific page when they click on the link

Tags: php, mysql

I have been asked to create some functionality in which

- marketing team send users a link to specific product page in emails or e-blasts.
- user clicks on the link
- link redirect the user to the website login page.
- After successful login user straight away goes to the product page.

NOTE: I don't want the user to go to the regular page after a successful login. I want user to straight away direct to product page after a successful login.

How this can be achieved. I use php. Any Ideas?

Please edit my Tags I don't know exactly where to direct this query to.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could append a key to the link like `http://example.com/login.php?view=product` then after login you could check for this flag `if(isset($_GET['view']) && $_GET['view'] == 'product')` and redirect appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some request variable on login page and you can redirect the logged in user based on the value of this new request variable. For example when user clicks your link (send through email) that hyperlink url will also have a request variable(providing Extra path in query String) with login page.
then ok login page you can test for value of this variable and redirect accordingly

Answer (score 1):

For example, redirect them in the 3rd step not just on `/login.php` but rather on `/login.php?returnTo=/productPageOrWhereverRedirectWasIssuedFrom.php`; and on the 3rd step redirect them to `$_GET['returnTo']` (if set).